# The modal doesnt open the data it had before opening, the data that is retrieved is the last data that was taken through the json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap

I want to open the specific image and caption, on which i click to open on the modal,
I cannot find where i am going wrong,
This is the modal file or the modal code,

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="items in items">
            <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{items.img}}" alt="{{items.alt}}"  ng-click="open()" /> <!--data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"-->
            <h4>{{items.alt}}</h4>
             <!--The Modal Starts here-->
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <!--Modal Content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Header</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <img ng-src="{{items.img}}" class="img-responsive" />
                                <h4>{{items.alt}}</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </script>
        </div>
```

This is the angularjs code i am using,

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui_bootstrap']);
    app.controller('ModalInstanceController', function ($swipe, $modalInstance, items) {
        $scope.items = items;
    });
    app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $timeout, $modal, $log) {
        $http.get("Data/ImageJson.json")
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.items = data.items;
        });

        $scope.open = function (_items) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                controller: "ModalInstanceCtrl",
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                resolve: {
                    items: function () {
                        return _items;
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

Comment: can u create a plnker

Comment: inside the `open` function controller should be `ModalInstanceController` not `ModalInstanceCtrl`

Comment: now i am getting this error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: show me ur json

Comment: Please describe how "it is not working."  Do portions of the form not render?  Javascript error?  Unexpected data/display values?